# Python - Can read JSON data but can't set to variable

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to be able to load a class instance from a JSON file.  For some reason, the JSON data can be read from the file (see the `print` line) but can't be set to a variable.

JSON file contents:

`{"key": 1}`

```
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    print(json.load(json_file)) # prints {'key': 1}
    class_dict = json.load(json_file)
```

I get this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

I tried `json.load` and `json.loads` with a string value.  I tried adding additional parameters to the `open` function.  None of it works.  I validated the JSON here: https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Did you try removing the call to `print`?

Comment: For some ungodly reason, that works.  I'd be curious why (maybe loading twice within `with` is prohibited?), but feel free to add it as an answer and I'll green check it.

Comment: Hi! You are reading the file twice. After the first read (using json.load()) it will leave the read cursor at the end of the file, so the second read will fail. Just change the order, first read it (json.load()) and then print it: print(class_dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Scott Hunter, you already read the file with the first json.load statement.  If you need to assign the contents directly you could rewind the file.

```
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    print(json.load(json_file))
    json_file.seek(0)
    class_dict =  json.load(json_file)
    print class_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the file twice by

```
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    print(json.load(json_file)) # prints {'key': 1}
    class_dict = json.load(json_file)
```

The first `json.load(json_file)` will load the open file fully, so the second time there is nothing more to read.

If you want to print it as well as assign it, assign it first, and then print it:

```
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    class_dict = json.load(json_file)
    print(class_dict) # prints {'key': 1}
```